# Increase max length of a text field?

Tags: 8, entities

Is there a simple way to increase the maxlength value of a plain text field that has data in it already?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To directly answer the question, there is no simple way in Drupal 8 to modify the schema for a field once it's been populated with data.

But, there is a more complicated way to manage it.

We've used the work done [here](http://www.jpstacey.info/blog/2017-07-21/altering-length-drupal-8-text-field-contains-data) by J-P Stacey to update a field in our platform.

- ALTER the database tables directly using raw SQL.
- Change the site configuration for the field.
- Force the current, "desired" schema records in Drupal to match.
- Force the "most recently installed" schema records to also match.

Additional information can be found in [this](https://www.metaltoad.com/blog/extending-drupal-8-fields-contain-data) article written by Marcus Bernal.

Comment: There’s no API for it? So the whole system is informed?

Comment: I haven't been able to find one for D8. This example [here](https://coderwall.com/p/uyidlq/updating-the-storage-definition-of-entities-that-already-have-content-in-drupal-8) is pretty close to what you need to do. The gist of it is: *collect the field data*, *remove the field from the db*,*define and add the new field*,*put the data back in*. 

I haven't tested this solution but there will be some challenges. If you have a lot of data you may run out of php memory. It also looks like you'll need to do some additional work to update the configs to match.